# Mysql select max and sort date

Tags: mysql

'tbl'

|     user    |   code   |         date          | 
|   user 1   |   8549   |   2016-02-01   |
|   user 2   |   7844   |   2016-02-17   |
|   user 1   |   8675   |   2016-02-16   |
|   user 3   |   2345   |   2016-02-21   |
|   user 2   |   8545   |   2016-02-08   |

I have this set of records 'tbl' and i query to get the distinct user with it's latest date

```
SELECT user, code, max(date) as dt from tbl GROUP BY user
```

it returns:

|     user    |   code   |         date          | 
|   user 1   |   8675   |   2016-02-16   |
|   user 2   |   7844   |   2016-02-17   |
|   user 3   |   2345   |   2016-02-16   |

my problem is that i have no idea how to sort the date to desc.
I want a result like this:

|     user    |   code   |         date          | 
|   user 1   |   8675   |   2016-02-16   |
|   user 3   |   2345   |   2016-02-16   |
|   user 2   |   7844   |   2016-02-17   |

Thanks :)

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?  Have you heard of using `ORDER BY`, e.g. `SELECT ... ORDER BY f_fr DESC` ?

Comment: thanks for responding i am really really new to stackover flow. i revised my question.

Comment: I tried using `ORDER BY date` but it returns the whole records instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT user, code, max(date) as dt from tbl GROUP BY user ) p
ORDER BY dt desc
```